# How to insert an item at position 0 in a Hive DB box?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-hive

I'm using Hive for Flutter. I want to insert every item at position 0 of a box. The items inside the box have to increase index automatically. If I use the 'add' method, the new item inserted takes the last position. This is not good for a List View. The last item inserted must be the first of the list in order to make it visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are automatically sorted, no insertion order is preserved:

> Boxes are sorted by lexicographically by key. Keys can either be
> strings or integers.

https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/198